# Autocomplete and suggestions in sphinxsearch

Tags: sphinx

I'm new in working with sphinx search
I want to make search engine for e-commerce to search product with auto complete and auto suggestions module. 
Any one know how to make it possible.

Comment: Well CALL QSUGGEST is you friend. http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2016/09/09/sphinx-2-3-2-beta/ but the specific of how to do it may vary, depending on your database, infustructure etc

Comment: I want best sphinxsearch Tutorial website

Comment: Well I don't know of a 'tutorial' website as such, but plenty of resources available if go digging http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2016/10/03/2-3-2-feature-built-in-suggests/ , and some useful reference code https://github.com/adriannuta/SphinxAutocompleteExample